# :hover feature like Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a z-index of 1 on individual divs, buttons, and h1 that are underneath an overlay. I'm trying to make it similar to the chrome developer tools :hover feature. In Dev Tools, when you hover over an individual element, it highlights, however in my case, I'd like it to come above the overlay. In dev tools, you can highlight a child div without it's parent highlighting, and that's what I'm looking to do too.

I've tried messing with opacity, but when it has a nested div, the nested div gets double the opacity and I don't want that. Here's the codepen and the code...

http://codepen.io/jareko999/pen/wWGpwz

HTML

```
<div class="cover">
</div>

<h1 class="title">Here's your website</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>The Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  z-index: 1;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38155/pexels-photo-38155.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #276cd6;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want to hover the element that is under the overlay or?

Comment: can you give link to show us what feature you want to add?

Comment: basically you have 2 options, first, make what you want to be on top on top with z-index and style them like your background (easy thing), second, listen on the overlay where the mouse is and if it is above an element which shall be on top. If so make it on top (not so easy).

Comment: I guess let's start here...I want to add a rgba(0,0,0,0.4) overlay on top of all divs without turning down the opacity of the actual div. Here's the codepen...

http://codepen.io/jareko999/pen/xOVWgY

This is a perfect example of why I can't turn opacity down. Each image would blend with one another. I just need each to have that overlay.